# Multiple points are not shown on map view

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift3

I have placed the Google Map button on route View Controller for google map.I have generated pod file and and  created the GoogleMapVC class .GoogleMapVC class is displaying only the last coordinates placed in the sequence (i.e last in sequence is  **self.coordinates(a:33.720805,b:73.057037,c:"ccc")** are only displayed).I want to display all coordinates mentioned in GoogleMapVC class .How i display all coordinates ?
Here is my GoogleMapVC class.You can download the sample project from this link for correction 
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv0b7w8dir9mxl3/IOS9DrawRouteMapKitTutorial.zip?dl=0

```
import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps
    class GoogleMapVC: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title="Google Map"

            self.coordinates(a:33.718619,b:73.075135,c:"aaa")
             self.coordinates(a:33.712162,b:73.049859,c:"bbb")
            self.coordinates(a:33.720805,b:73.057037,c:"ccc")
}
    func coordinates(a:Double ,b:Double, c:String)  {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:a,longitude:b, zoom:14)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera:camera)
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = c
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.map = mapView
        self.view = mapView
    }

}
```

Comment: show the below solution you should bounds the map with CLLOcationCoordinate2D to show all position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
class GoogleMapVC: UIViewController {

    var mapView : GMSMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title="Google Map"

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 33.718619,longitude: 73.075135, zoom:8)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera:camera)    
        self.view = mapView

        self.coordinates(a:33.718619,b:73.075135,c:"aaa")
        self.coordinates(a:33.712162,b:73.049859,c:"bbb")
        self.coordinates(a:33.720805,b:73.057037,c:"ccc")
    }

    func coordinates(a:Double ,b:Double, c:String)  {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: a, longitude: b)
        marker.snippet = c
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.map = mapView
    }

}
```

This will show a much higher view and you should see all the markers on the map.

Comment: let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 33.718619,longitude: 73.075135, zoom:8)
         it s static solution what if number or coordinates change at runtime??

Comment: marker.map = mapView
                                                                           self.view = mapView  at these two lines     Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'mapView'

Comment: this is just to check if the map is all zoomed in at a particular location and the markers are not visible due to this. This line can be replaced after the checking that markers are adding there

Comment: @frincit do you have a mapview outlet or are you creating mapview programatically? Then just create a global mapView object. so that map view is not added or assigned to the view everytime.

Comment: marker.map = mapView
        self.view = mapView  at these two lines     Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'mapView'

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that mapView will only show last set coordinates because you are setting self.coordinates 3 times that means updating the value every time.

So if you want to show multiple point consider adding all the different coordinates to array and also modify your method

```
let locations = [
    ["latitude": 33.718619, "longitude": 73.075135],
    ["latitude": 33.712162, "longitude": 73.049859],
    ["latitude": 33.720805, "longitude": 73.057037]
]

for location in locations {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: I am not using MK mapview i am using google map  .    func coordinates(a:Double ,b:Double, c:String) have code for google map

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are using MKMapView or google maps, you cant add multiple annotations with your approach, you will need to use array and you should not initialise mapView everytime you call that function.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `self.coordinates(a:33.720805,b:73.057037,c:"ccc")` only at once if you want to show point only once on map.

Comment: the question is multiple points are not shown only  last coordinates in sequence are shown .I want to show multiple points

Comment: this question is already posted please see it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191436/adding-multiple-pins-on-google-map-in-ios

Comment: the above question is using objective c .i am using swift